# github clone and push command not working

Tags: git, bash, github

I am trying to connect to my github account through git bash, but I unable to do so the command I am trying is:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/userName/file-name.git
Cloning into 'file-name'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/userName/file-name.git/' not found
```

The same error is coming up when i am trying to push:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/userName/file.git
git push -u origin master
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/userName/file.git/' not found
```

Previously it was working fine but suddenly stopped. I used the command:
`git config --global http.sslVerify false`
to connect to the github but still not working.

Comment: Well, does `https://github.com/userName/file-name.git` exist? I *assume* `userName` and `file-name` are placeholders.

Comment: @Biffen Yes file-name exist, as the github account is my own and i have created it a few days back. Also username and file-name are palceholders.

Comment: Double-check the URL. Or copy it from the repo's web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a temporary problem which is network specific , trying flushing your DNS using ipconfig/dnsflush(On windows) from the command prompt .It might also be restricted by some third party administrator.Or else trying reconnecting with the network again .

Comment: Yes, I think there was intermittent issue with the network. Tried after flushing DNS and clearing cache and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your username and password? You may not have permission for this repository.
And secondly, I'm not sure this is the problem, but your path should look like this https://github.com/userName/repository-name.git instead of file-name.

Comment: Yeah I have added my user name and email using:

Comment: git config --global user.name "username" and user email In the same way

Comment: @MishaHusiuk If it's a matter of permission, would one really get ‘*repository […] not found*’?

Comment: If it's not a public repository then all your attempts to access it( for example clone) will fail with message 'repository […] not found' until you log in with user who has access to this repo.